# Angular2 nested observable cart total but value return undefined

Tags: angular, angularfire2

I want to calculate the total amount of the shopping basket. I have **ShoppingCartItem** and **Product** tables. I have bellow code

```
cartTotals(qty = 0, total = 0) {
return this.af.database.list('ShoppingCartItem')
  .map(carts => {
    carts.map(cart => {
        this.af.database.object(`Product/${cart.productId}`)
        .subscribe(d => {
            cart.product = d;
        });
      return cart;
    });
    carts.forEach(cartItem => {
        qty += cartItem.quantity;
        total += cartItem.quantity * cartItem.product.price;
        // console.log(cartItem);
    });
    return {qty, total};
  });
}
```

Returning **qty** value works but **total** value returning undefined

This [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/cWdXRGNk08NDtArDj10O)

Comment: `total` cannot be `undefined` because its' default value is number 0

Comment: cartItem.product.price return undefined because total value return undefined or error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I want to calculate the sum of the ShoppingCart at Firebase with Angularfire2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40833704/i-want-to-calculate-the-sum-of-the-shoppingcart-at-firebase-with-angularfire2)

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if this works, since I do not have the whole of your source code and API data.

```
cartTotals(qty = 0, total = 0) {
  return this.af.database.list('ShoppingCartItem')
   .map(carts => carts.map(cart => cart.product = this.findProductFromCartId(cart.productId)))
   .map(carts => carts.map(cartItem => {
        cartItem.qty = cartItem.quantity + qty;
        cartItem.total = (cartItem.quantity * cartItem.product.price) + total;
        return cartItem;
    });
}

findProductFromCartId(id) {
    return this.af.database.object(`Product/${id}`)
        .flatMap(product => Observable.combineLatest(product));//add this onlyIF its returned FirebaseObservable Object
}
```

Comment: Returning such an error : Property 'qty' does not exist on type 'Observable<any>'. More detailed description of this link [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40833704/i-want-to-calculate-the-sum-of-the-shoppingcart-at-firebase-with-angularfire2). I think you will give a better idea. Thank you for your interest.

Comment: to tell you first thing about your code, data is separated in your API data which is great. But the frontend logic to get the product price is not good.
Can you please share the mock data

Comment: this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/cWdXRGNk08NDtArDj10O?p=preview). Can you help?