# I want to calculate the sum of the ShoppingCart at Firebase with Angularfire2

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, angularfire2

I'm building an experimental application that uses Angular2, Firebase and AngularFire2.
This is what my data looks like:

```
{
  "ShoppingCartItem":
      {
        "item1":{
            "quantity": 2,
            "productId": "abc"
        },
        "item2":{
            "quantity": 1,
            "productId": "bcd"
        }
      }
  "Product"
      {
        "abc":{
            "name": "product1",
            "price": 5
    },
        "bcd":{
            "name": "product2",
            "price": 6
        }
    }
}
```

Below are my cart.ts

```
this.items = this.af.database.list('ShoppingCartItem')
          .map(carts => {
            return carts.map(item => {
              item.product = this.af.database.object(`Product/${item.productId}`);
              return item;
            });
          });
```

Below are my cart.html

```
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of (items | async)">
        <td>{{(item.product | async)?.name}}</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="quantity" [(ngModel)]="item.quantity" size="1" class="form-control"></td>
        <td>{{(item.product | async)?.price | number: '.2'}}</td>
        <td>{{(item.product | async)?.price * item.quantity | number: '.2'}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
<tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" class="text-right">
        <strong>Total :</strong>
      </td>
      <td colspan="2" class="text-left">
        ?????????
      </td>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
```

I want to calculate the sum of the ShoppingCart. So I want to find the value of (2*5) + (1*6) = 16 as the data shows. How do i do it.

This [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/cWdXRGNk08NDtArDj10O)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this code:

```
carts.map(cart => {
    this.af.database.object(`Product/${cart.productId}`)
    .subscribe(d => {
        cart.product = d;
    });
  return cart;
});
carts.forEach(cartItem => {
    qty += cartItem.quantity;
    total += cartItem.quantity * cartItem.product.price;
    // console.log(cartItem);
});
```

Two calls: `carts.map` and `carts.forEach` are synchronous and happen one after another. But loading of products (via `af.database.object`) is asynchronous so when you iterating over cartItem products not been loaded yet.

The solution would be to chain product loading and total calculation. See [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/D7BhhGWcDwh9Yopj36uD?p=preview).

Comment: Great! I am working on a project and I am going to need a lot of RXJS. Thanks to you, I believe I could learn something. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Firebase, first thing I notice is key names. Fix them like this. Where `cart.$key` is some hashcode e.g. `-KXeML1Na9qCsvK4JSyQ`.

```
{
  "ShoppingCartItem": {
    -KXeML1OkDyUVTAdHYPx : {
      -KXeML1OkDyUVTAdHYPx: true,
      -KXeML1PP4faQG2Z3fzU: true
    },
    -KXeML1Na9qCsvK4JSyQ: {
      -KXeML1PP4faQG2Z3fzU: true
    }
  },
  "Products": {
    -KXeML1OkDyUVTAdHYPx:{
      "name": "product1",
      "price": 5
    },
    -KXeML1PP4faQG2Z3fzU:{
      "name": "product2",
      "price": 6
    }
  }
}
```

Now rewrite your frontend logic. Please write and export suitable `Product` class as well. Put below inside `shoppingcart.service.ts`

```
findProductKeysForCart(cartId: string): Observable<string[]> {
 return this.database.list('ShoppingCartItem', {
    query: {
      orderByKey: true,
      equalTo: cartId
    }
  })
    //.do(console.log)// Check whats coming,
    //.map(result => result[0])// might be needed
    .map(sci => sci.map(product => product.$key));
}

findProductsForProductKeys(productKeys$: Observable<string[]>): Observable<Product[]> {
  return productKeys$
    .map(productKeys => productKeys.map(productKey => this.database.object(`Products/${productKey}`)))
    .flatMap(prodObservables => Observable.combineLatest(prodObservables));
}


findAllProductsForCart(cartId): Observable<Product[]> {
    //this fn gets your Products for a cart
    return this.findProductsForProductKeys(this.findProductKeysForCart(cartId));
}
```

NOW, do your final calculations either in Product class or subscribe.
Below would go inside `DisplayCart.component.ts`

```
items;
constructor(private shoppingCartService: ShoppingCartService){}

ngOnInit(){
  const items$ = this.shoppingCartService.findAllProductsForCart(this.cartId);

 items$.subscribe(items => this.items = items);
}
```

You still need to complete the remaining stuff on your own, good luck.

Comment: Your method is a different method. I'm having trouble listing cart information. My example has quantity information in the ShoppinCartItem table. The Product table also comes with price information. I want to multiply the sum by the price. So I want to find the value of (2*5) + (1*6) = 16 as the data shows. How do i do it.

Comment: This [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/cWdXRGNk08NDtArDj10O). Can you help?

Comment: @GökmenSaralu still dont get it. Im saying the way you have written the code is very bad. You need to write the code first in correct way, and with above code you can get the object easily.

Comment: I am new to Nosql Database, RealTime Database and RXJS. I found these examples.Your example you gave you didn't account for the quantity never. I don't want to discuss the structure of the model. All I want is to pull the quantity information from a document, pull the price information from other documents. I want to do backend computation and print on the to front end. This [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/cWdXRGNk08NDtArDj10O) also sample code is available. You can see the error from the console. Thank you for your concern.