# Angularfire2 Observable concat not working

Tags: angular, rxjs5, angularfire2

This is what my data looks like:

```
{
  "Category" : {
    "-KVuXp30tdhR1CqmCb_X" : {
      "name" : "Category1",
      "parentCategoryId" : ""
  },
    "-KVuY0CjGePvUo2qVcGb" : {
      "name" : "Category2",
      "parentCategoryId" : ""
  },
    "-KW9U76wJg-4hgnMUvu2" : {
      "name" : "Category1sub1",
      "parentCategoryId" : "-KVuXp30tdhR1CqmCb_X"
  },
    "-KYODOJXjqnRMkVSsIFs" : {
      "name" : "Category2Sub1",
      "parentCategoryId" : "-KVuY0CjGePvUo2qVcGb"
  },
    "-KYOKdbX22UCeU2EZcYQ" : {
      "name" : "Category1Sub3",
      "parentCategoryId" : "-KVuXp30tdhR1CqmCb_X"
  },
    "-KYOM3dV9pX0Isx-7V5C" : {
      "name" : "Category2Sub2",
      "parentCategoryId" : "-KVuY0CjGePvUo2qVcGb"
  }
 }
}
```

I want to list under main categories and sub categories.

- Category1
- Category2
- Category1 >> Category1sub1
- Category2 >> Category2Sub1
- Category1 >> Category1Sub3
- Category2 >> Category2Sub2

The sample code [here (plunker)](https://plnkr.co/edit/zfilRg).

What am I doing wrong. How do i do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AngularFire`'s list method returns Observabel that never ends so there is no point in using it in `concat`. If you want to get only first value you should use `take`.

There is no `db` property on your service, hence

```
this.db.object
```

will throw an error (you didn't see an error because that code hadn't been executed).

Look at this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Kc23OhyV86RvSneGL0XU?p=preview) and ask if something is not clear.

Comment: Yes, I made a mistake there. I'm learning about RxJS new. Another problem is on the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40833704/i-want-to-calculate-the-sum-of-the-shoppingcart-at-firebase-with-angularfire2). Can you help with that? Thank you for your help.